# ImportError: cannot import name 'registerParameterItemType

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I am trying to run the code in the following link "https://github.com/habom2310/Heart-rate-measurement-using-camera"

but I get import error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ialam/Desktop/Heart-rate-measurement-using-camera-master/Heart-rate-measurement-using-camera-master/GUI.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pyqtgraph as pg
  File "C:\Users\ialam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\__init__.py", line 239, in <module>
    from .widgets.ScatterPlotWidget import * 
  File "C:\Users\ialam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\ScatterPlotWidget.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .DataFilterWidget import DataFilterParameter
  File "C:\Users\ialam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\DataFilterWidget.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .. import parametertree as ptree
  File "C:\Users\ialam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\parametertree\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .ParameterSystem import ParameterSystem, SystemSolver
  File "C:\Users\ialam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\parametertree\ParameterSystem.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .parameterTypes import GroupParameter
  File "C:\Users\ialam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\parametertree\parameterTypes\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..Parameter import registerParameterItemType, registerParameterType
ImportError: cannot import name 'registerParameterItemType' from 'pyqtgraph.parametertree.Parameter' (C:\Users\ialam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\parametertree\Parameter.py)
```

can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Do you use pycharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you run the following, as mentioned in the GitHub repo:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```